# Gitlab Runner error exec: "sh": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have this error when running a container on Gitlab CI

`ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown (exec.go:57:0s)`

My .Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.16-alpine AS builder
ENV \
    OUTDIR='/out' \
    GO111MODULE='on'    

WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod /app/
COPY go.sum /app/
RUN go mod download
COPY . /app/
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOBIN=${OUTDIR}/usr/bin/ go install .

FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /out/ /
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/app-cli"]
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - validation

validation:
  image:
    name: gitlab.mycompany.net:4567/myteam/app-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: validation
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID'
  script:
    - ls
```

Is this error related to my dockerfile or the gitlab ci ?

I can run this locally by
`docker run --rm -ti gitlab.mycompany.net:4567/myteam/app-cli:latest`
but not at gitlab runner

Answer (score 1):

`Giving an empty entrypoint` and `not giving the entrypoint at all` are not the same thing.

In the `docker run` command, you are not giving any entrypoint. Hence, the docker image runs with the default entrypoint  `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/app-cli"]`.

In the `gitlab-ci`, you are overwriting the default entrypoint with an empty one `entrypoint: [""]` where `executable file not found`.

Try this:

```yaml
validation:
  image:
    name: gitlab.mycompany.net:4567/myteam/app-cli:latest
    entrypoint: ["/usr/bin/app-cli"]
```

Comment: I've tried that and it returns this error
`Error: unknown command "sh" for "app-cli"`

Comment: @Roy, the rule is probably evaluated in the container and therefore requires a shell (which is obviously not present in scratch). Output the remaining arguments to verify.

Comment: "Output the remaining arguments to verify" could you elaborate more and how to do this @Peter?

Comment: @Roy, make app-cli output os.Args.

Answer (score 0):

Besides overwriting the entrypoint as already pointed out, the issue is that you are calling `ls` as the script which requires a shell.
Try just calling your application in the script part `/usr/bin/app-cli`.

Comment: does it mean I can't run ls, cat , etc?

Comment: I've tried that and it returns this error Error: unknown command "sh" for "app-cli"

Comment: It looks like the script part is always run in a shell, thus using from scratch won't work.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer

I just need to change the
`FROM scratch` to
`FROM alpine:latest`
so now I can use the `sh`

Comment: Nothing is installed in scratch, it is the smallest most minimal container you could have, thus it does not come with an OS or shell